# How can we pass object as a parameter to a function name in Object value?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I want to pass an object to a function which is a value of another object. Is this possible, how can we do that? I can pass a string easily and a variable as a string. But, cannot pass as an object.

I have 2 objects like:

```
var test1 = "qwerty";
var test2 = { qwerty: "sdaf" };
```

I want to pass these objects as a parameter to an object value like the below.

```
var props = {
   event: `backdropEvent("${test}")`,
}
```

```
function backdropEvent(e){
 console.log(e)
}
```

When I tried to pass `test1` I get it as a string. How can I pass the `test2` object?

```js
var test1 = "qwerty";
var test2 = { qwerty: "sdaf" };

var props = {
   event: `backdropEvent("${test2}")`,
}

function backdropEvent(e){
 console.log(e)
}

function testFn(){
testFn2(props);
}

function testFn2(e){
var x = Function(e.event);
x();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testFn()"> click me </button>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused... why not `event: backdropEvent(test2)`, without turning the var into a string? That said, `backdropEvent` doesn't return anything, so I'm not sure why you'd want to assign this to a value. What are you trying to achieve with all of this pseudocode in any event?

Comment: So, my purpose here is: I want to open a modal that contains Buttons that will have events declared based on this object's properties. If I assign a function directly to the object as a value then I cannot assign the value as an EVENT to the button in the modal.

Comment: I'm still not really understanding, but this smells a lot like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) because the code here is very unusual. There is probably a much easier way to go about doing this if you don't mind providing more context. Events aren't usually things you assign--the DOM passes the event object to you when you register handlers, so I'm not really sure what the purpose of your event object is, exactly. If you have `props`, it suggests you're using React. If this is the case then I'd be even more worried about this.

Comment: To keep it simple: I want to bind an event to a Button in a modal which will only be shown based on a condition. I am using plain JS, no frameworks.

Comment: OK, so is there a problem with `Button.addEventListener("your event", event => /* your event handler */)`? I still have no motivation for the extra Rube Goldbergian hijinks, if you'll pardon the expression.

Comment: I have no idea of the BUTTON ID or class. It can be a Button or a link etc. It is not constant. I need to pass a function name in the object properties so that the function should be assigned wherever needed in the modal. That function should execute only when there is an action performed by User in the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken since its a little hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish but I beleive that you want to use [function binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
const test2 = { qwerty: "sdaf" };

const backdropEvent = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}

const props = {
    event: backdropEvent.bind(null, test2)
}

props.event()
```